# React Native, accessing a single element from an array nested in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

how can I access a single element from an array nested in a state like this

```
state = {
    modal: false,
    post: [
      {
        key: "1",
        title: "A Good Boi",
        des: "He's a good boi and every one know it.",
        image: require("../assets/dog.jpg"),
      },
      {
        key: "2",
        title: "John Cena",
        des: "As you can see, You can't see me!",
        image: require("../assets/cena.jpg"),
      },
    ]
  };
.....
    <MyList.Provider
          value={{
           
          }}
        >
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.post}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={0.7}
                  onPress={() => this.deleteItem(item)}
                  style={styles.Delete}
                >
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="delete" color="red" size={30} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={0.7}
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Edit", item)}
                  style={styles.Edit}
                >
                  <MaterialCommunityIcons
                    name="playlist-edit"
                    color="green"
                    size={35}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Card
                  title={item.title}
                  subTitle={item.des}
                  image={item.image}
                  onPress={() =>
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("Details", item)
                  }
                />
              </>
            )}
          />
        </MyList.Provider>
```

how can I do this like `this.state.post({title})` or some way else??
I need to use this values with context so I can share and change some particular data with between 2 screens.  I know  to pass data I need to use context or navigation.navigate("route name",item). But if I use navigation I won't able to edit it but how can I pass data in context value from array set, if I do this.state.post it will return whole list and if i do this.state.post[0].title it will return only title of that post. So how can i do this? Please help

Comment: You're asking how to access an array element's property?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `this.state.post[0].title` to access a specific element's title. In general: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: I read about this.state.post[0].title but how can I pass key instead of 0 I'm using context.provider on flat list

Answer (score 0):

You have to indicate the index of the object you’re trying to access in the array. For instance to access the first object in the array you can do this
`this.state.post[0]`

Comment: i know that but instead of 0 how can I pass key of that array set so that if user click on that post it will able to edit that post

Comment: You’d need to do that by mapping the array or using a flatlist. If you need help with that let me know

Comment: yes I need help a lot thank you,  I already have flat list I will edit my question and add that see and please help

Comment: if i use context inside flat list i won't able to do setState

Comment: I have just posted a new answer

Answer (score 0):

below is my solution which follows the logic i think you are trying to achieve. I have used a flatlist
Let me know if it helps

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false,
      post: [
        {
          key: "1",
          title: "A Good Boi",
          des: "He's a good boi and every one know it.",
          image: require("../assets/dog.jpg"),
        },
        {
          key: "2",
          title: "John Cena",
          des: "As you can see, You can't see me!",
          image: require("../assets/cena.jpg"),
        },
      ]
    };
  }

  handleEdit(item) {
    const { post } = this.state;
    const extractIndex = post.findIndex(e => e.key === item.key);
    const newPost = post[extractIndex];

    this.props.navigation.navigate('Edit', { newPost })
    this.setState({ post });
  }

  handleDelete(item) {
    const { post } = this.state;
    const newPost = post.filter(e => e.key !== item.key);
    this.setState({ post: newPost });
  }

  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {item.title}
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity key={item.key} onPress={this.handleEdit.bind(this, item)}>
          <Text>Edit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity key={item.key} onPress={this.handleDelete.bind(this, item)}>
          <Text>Delete</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList 
          data={this.state.post}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          extraData={this.state}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: that's great but this will work only in one screen I need to pass data to another screen which is edit screen and edit data from that screen actually its my task

Comment: thank you and if I click to edit it sill direct me to edit page for that post i click edit for and how can i save that editing on edit page

Comment: for proper state management, you would need to use redux

Comment: oh, thnx for help

Answer (score 0):

Use .map() function
Ex-

var cat_data = categories_list.map(function (item) {

```
var cat_data = categories_list.map(function (item) {
    return {
      name: item.Name,
      thumb_url: item.PictureModel.ImageUrl,
      cat_id: item.Id.toString(),
    };
  });
  this.setState({
    data: cat_data,      
  });
```